# How to show the first N elements of a block and hide the others in css?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I am trying to hide the first 3 elements having the class `.row` inside the block `.container`.

What I'm doing is hiding all the `.row` first, and then I am trying to display the first 3 `.row` by using `.row:nth-child(-n+3)`

jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/z8fMr/1/

```css
.row {
  display: none;
}

.row:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="notarow">I'm not a row and I must remain visible</div>
  <div class="row">Row 1</div>
  <div class="row">Row 2</div>
  <div class="row">Row 3</div>
  <div class="row">Row 4</div>
  <div class="row">Row 5</div>
  <div class="row">Row 6</div>

</div>
```

I have two problems here:

1. Row 3 is not displayed; am I using nth-child in the wrong way?
2. Is there a better practice than hiding everything and then creating a specific rule to display the n first elements that I want? Is there a way in CSS to just display the first 3 `.row` and then hide all the other `.row`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

1. You have a `.notarow` as the first child, so you have to account for that in your `:nth-child()` formula. Because of that `.notarow`, your first `.row` becomes the second child overall of the parent, so you have to count starting from the second to the fourth:

   ```
    .row:nth-child(-n+4) {
        display: block;
    }
   ```

   [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/z8fMr/2)

   ```css
   .row {
       display: none;
   }

   .row:nth-child(-n+4) {
       display: block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="content">
       <div class="notarow">I'm not a row and I must remain visible</div>
       <div class="row">Row 1</div>
       <div class="row">Row 2</div>
       <div class="row">Row 3</div>
       <div class="row">Row 4</div>
       <div class="row">Row 5</div>
       <div class="row">Row 6</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. What you're doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear explanation BoltClock. I thought (-n+3) would select the first 3 .row whatever element there is before.

Comment: Do you also know if there is also a best practice for what I want to do? Hiding everything and then showing the first 3 elements => is there a better way to show the first N elements only in css? thanks

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a better way. Using `:nth-child()` like this is fine as long as you accommodate for the actual structure and it is predictable enough.

Comment: What does the minus (-) do here?

Comment: @tmyie: It flips the n so that it counts backwards starting from 0, so you get 0+4, -1+4, -2+4, -3+4... resulting in the 4th, 3rd, 2nd and 1st children.

Comment: up for genius hack! :)

Answer (score 23):

You don't even need CSS3 selectors:

```
.row + .row + .row + .row {
    display: none;
}
```

This should work even in IE7.
[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fMr/5/)

Answer (score 10):

Also, like Giovanni's solution, something like this could also work.

```
.container > .row:nth-child(3) ~ .row {
    /* this rule targets the rows after the 3rd .row */
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer by Googling "css show first n elements", but the question now seems to be the opposite (hiding first n elements)

```
:nth-child(n+4)
```

^ this will work if you're looking for what I was looking for