# Ruby loop through first 20 items then add a see more to see the rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a feature that allows a user to list their clients.

Currently I am taking the text they enter and separating it by line and looping through each one.

```
agency.client_list.to_s.gsub(/[,]/, "\n").split("\n").each do |client|
    li itemprop="customer" = client
```

What I would like to do is show the first 20, then have a see more button that shows the rest. I've already done `.first(20)`, but I'm having trouble figuring out the rest.

Comment: `/[,]/` is the same as `/,/` and `","`.

Comment: The solution to this is much too involved. You could dump all the clients, and use CSS to hide elements after 20, then use JS to show (changing the styles). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922165/how-to-show-the-first-n-elements-of-a-block-and-hide-the-others-in-css. OR use AJAX. Try that then come back if you get stuck.

Comment: The search terms you're looking for are ["Rails pagination."](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+pagination&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari) There are multiple gems for this and many, many tutorials readily available on Google.