# Style class by attribute value (nth-child)

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to append style on a class depending on the value in the parents data-attribute.

In my case, rating starts.

If data-rating is for ex. 3, the first three starts should be filled with a color.

I assume nth-child will do the trick, but i can't manage it to work..

This is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="3">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span> /* Filled */
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span> /* Filled */
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span> /* Filled */
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using sass.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CSS support for reading values from `data-` attributes are still extremely limited, you cannot rely on reading the `data-rating` to dynamically apply `:nth-child` rules. However, since you are using a CSS preprocessor (SASS as you mentioned), you can use a [`@for` loop](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) to generate all the necessary selectors required. The caveat to this solution is that you will need to pre-determinate the maximum rating (in this case, it is `5`).

The SASS code below (also [available as a gist](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b8618a872e252c6b0c015abb1d057686)) will do more or less what you're intending to achieve. To [select for the first `x` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922165/how-to-show-the-first-n-elements-of-a-block-and-hide-the-others-in-css), you can use the `:nth-child(-n+x)` selector rule.

1. Use the SASS `@for` loop to iterate through all possible star ratings (1 through `x`, where `x` is 5 in your case)
2. Generate a selector that targets the `.rating[data-rating='x']`
3. In each `.rating` selector, you use the `nth-child` trick above to style the first `x` stars.

```css
// Some basic configuration
$stars: 5;
$star-color: #FFD464;

// Baes styles for unfilled stars
.rating {
  .star {
    color: #ccc;
  }
}

// Create custom nth-child selectors for each data-rating value
@for $i from 1 through $stars {
  .rating[data-rating='#{$i}'] {
    .star:nth-child(-n+#{$i}) {
      color: $star-color;
    }
  }
}
```

> **Disclaimer:** The only major drawback of this method is that it gets bloated quickly when you have too many stars. Having 5 stars is not an issue, since you will only generate 5 different sets of rules (plus with the adent of gzipping and CSS minification, the code bloat does not incur a heavy overhead). Imagine if you have a 10-star rating system, the selector rules will be overly verbose: in that case, you might want to consider a JS-based solution.

Here is a proof-of-concept example using the compiled SASS code above:

```css
.rating .star {
  color: #ccc;
}

.rating[data-rating='1'] .star:nth-child(-n+1) {
  color: #FFD464;
}

.rating[data-rating='2'] .star:nth-child(-n+2) {
  color: #FFD464;
}

.rating[data-rating='3'] .star:nth-child(-n+3) {
  color: #FFD464;
}

.rating[data-rating='4'] .star:nth-child(-n+4) {
  color: #FFD464;
}

.rating[data-rating='5'] .star:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="1">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="2">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="3">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="4">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="5">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'>&#9733;</span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'>&#9733;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Even better: Use pseudo-elements to change star glyphs

If you want to use different glyphs for filled and unfilled stars, that is also possible. You simply use the `::before` (or `::after`) pseudo-element to inject the correct glyph conditionally (`\2605` for filled star, `\2606` for empty star) , again using the same iterative logic as above:

```
// Some basic configuration
$stars: 5;
$star-color: #FFD464;
$stars-filled: "\2605";
$stars-empty: "\2606";

// Baes styles for unfilled stars
.rating {
  .star {
    color: #ccc;
    &::before {
      content: $stars-empty;
    }
  }
}

// Create custom nth-child selectors for each data-rating value
@for $i from 1 through $stars {
  .rating[data-rating='#{$i}'] {
    .star:nth-child(-n+#{$i}) {
      color: $star-color;

      &::before {
        content: $stars-filled;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.rating .star {
  color: #ccc;
}
.rating .star::before {
  content: "☆";
}

.rating[data-rating='1'] .star:nth-child(-n+1) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
.rating[data-rating='1'] .star:nth-child(-n+1)::before {
  content: "★";
}

.rating[data-rating='2'] .star:nth-child(-n+2) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
.rating[data-rating='2'] .star:nth-child(-n+2)::before {
  content: "★";
}

.rating[data-rating='3'] .star:nth-child(-n+3) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
.rating[data-rating='3'] .star:nth-child(-n+3)::before {
  content: "★";
}

.rating[data-rating='4'] .star:nth-child(-n+4) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
.rating[data-rating='4'] .star:nth-child(-n+4)::before {
  content: "★";
}

.rating[data-rating='5'] .star:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: #FFD464;
}
.rating[data-rating='5'] .star:nth-child(-n+5)::before {
  content: "★";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="1">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="2">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="3">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="4">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="rating" data-rating="5">
        <span class="star" data-score='1'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='2'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='3'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Glidarn You're welcome. I have updated with another example, if you want to use different glyph for the stars :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

This bit of sass code all you need. [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/eGWRrb)

```
 @for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .rating[data-rating="#{$i}"] {
      .fa-star:nth-child(-n+#{$i}) {
          color: yellow;
      }
  }
}
```

Check out the compiled css and full code.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.container {
  margin: 25px 50px;
}

.rating[data-rating="1"] .fa-star:nth-child(-n+1) {
  color: yellow;
}

.rating[data-rating="2"] .fa-star:nth-child(-n+2) {
  color: yellow;
}

.rating[data-rating="3"] .fa-star:nth-child(-n+3) {
  color: yellow;
}

.rating[data-rating="4"] .fa-star:nth-child(-n+4) {
  color: yellow;
}

.rating[data-rating="5"] .fa-star:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--  When data rating is 3 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="3">
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='1'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='2'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='3'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>

<!--  When data rating is 2 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="2">
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='1'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='2'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='3'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>


<!--  When data rating is 1 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="rating" data-rating="1">
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='1'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='2'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='3'></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='4'></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star" data-score='5'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass is a css generator. There's no interaction between sass and html like in js and html. So it's not possible from sass to go inside the html and take an attribute value.

What you need is a js/jquery solution.

for example: `$(".star:nth-child(-n+"+$(".rating").attr("data-rating")+")").css("background","red")`

Comment: Not necessarily: you can use `@for` loop in SASS to generate all the selectors to target each possible rating. The output will be verbose, but with gzip compression and CSS minification it's not too bad... unless we are talking about 1000-star ratings ;)

Comment: Well, if you don't want to end up with 50 selectors for one thing i think jquery is better. It may not be the only thing he wants that kind of stuff. The proper way would be to do it smartly not overflowing your css file.