# How to limit the number of elements found by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While **scraping** a webpage using BeautifulSoup, is there a way to limit the number of elements found by the find method family.

For eg if I want only the first 5  tags can I do this using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.find_all()` and `.select()` return standard python list, so you can use for example `[:5]` to get only first 5 results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div>Tag 1</div>
<div>Tag 2</div>
<div>Tag 3</div>
<div>Tag 4</div>
<div>Tag 5</div>
<div>Tag 6</div>
<div>Tag 7</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div')[:5]:
    print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
Tag 1
Tag 2
Tag 3
Tag 4
Tag 5
```

---

EDIT: You can use CSS selector for selecting first 5 elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div>Tag 1</div>
<div>Tag 2</div>
<div>Tag 3</div>
<div>Tag 4</div>
<div>Tag 5</div>
<div>Tag 6</div>
<div>Tag 7</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('div:nth-of-type(-n+5)'):
    print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
Tag 1
Tag 2
Tag 3
Tag 4
Tag 5
```

Comment: This is just selecting the first 5 from the list generated right? I wanted to reduce the runtime, I'm already doing something similar

Comment: @Karmah24 Yes, it is returning first 5 elements from all elements found by `.find_all()`

Comment: Can I terminate the search after the first five somehow?

Comment: thanks could you tell what the nth-of-type(-n+5) does?

Comment: @Karmah24 Try [this site](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) It's about `:nth-child()`, but similar rules apply here as well. Or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922165/how-to-show-the-first-n-elements-of-a-block-and-hide-the-others-in-css