# CSS select parent element with specific number of child

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `class language` this `div` contain a `ul` with 10 `li`

I'm trying to select the different ul base on the number of type `nth-of-type` then select the li child using `nth-child`

I'm trying to make the same design that appear in the picture below

I want to make the same thing in the picture all the li are green but in the first ul the last li is gray in the second ul the last 3 li are gray

I tried like below but it doesn't work

How can i make the same design using css

```css
.language {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

h4 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

.language ul:first-of-type li:last-child {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.language ul::nth-of-type(2) li:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="language">
  <h4>arabic</h4>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="language">
  <h4>english</h4>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @TemaniAfif i want to make the same thing in the picture all the li are green but in the first ul the last li is gray in the second ul the last 3 li are gray

Comment: so you make all of them grey then you select the first N element to make them green

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922165/8620333 (replace display with your coloration)