# Limit html list/div results with css

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically generated list (via third-party widget) that lists tour dates.

HTML served like this....

```
<div data-event-id="1" class="event ok">content</div>
<div data-event-id="2" class="event ok">content</div>
<div data-event-id="3" class="event ok">content</div>
```

Is there a way I can HIDE results with CSS beyond a certain point?

That is, if the widget pulls in 50 events, I only want to show the first 5.
How do I '**display:none**" on all results beyond the first 5?

Comment: My first thought is to look at the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) or [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class selectors, though those are usually used for repeating patterns.

Comment: See [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922208/17300) on the question [_How to show the first N elements of a block and hide the others in css?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922165/17300)

Answer (score 0):

Use a container with a fixed height and `overflow-y: hidden`:

```css
.container {
        height: 55px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div data-event-id="1" class="event ok">content1</div>
    <div data-event-id="2" class="event ok">content2</div>
    <div data-event-id="3" class="event ok">content3</div>
    <div data-event-id="4" class="event ok">content4</div>
    <div data-event-id="5" class="event ok">content5</div>
    <div data-event-id="6" class="event ok">content6</div>
    <div data-event-id="7" class="event ok">content7</div>
    <div data-event-id="8" class="event ok">content8</div>
    <div data-event-id="9" class="event ok">content9</div>
    <div data-event-id="10" class="event ok">content10</div>
    <div data-event-id="11" class="event ok">content11</div>
    <div data-event-id="12" class="event ok">content12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That has some problem across devices/being responsive.

Comment: If you're going to use a fixed height that height better be based on _ems_ or _rems_ — at 55px the number of rows that are visible will change, depending on the font size, and you'll probably have a line where the bottom of the text is cut off.